# Effect of scaling data on ARMA coefficients

Tags: estimation, arima, garch, parameterization, scale-invariance

For numerical stability, I thought it might be a good idea to scale my data before feeding them into an ARMA GARCH model. I have gone through a few older posts and understand the affect scaling innovations/residuals have on GARCH, but what effect does it have on the ARMA coefficients?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the only effect is on the constant/intercept term.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scale-invariant analysis of time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/scale-invariant-analysis-of-time-series). (See also the comments under the answer.) See also ["scaling in time series"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405597).